# Why renderTo don't work in xtype

Tags: extjs

Simple code:

```
var myPanel = {
    xtype : 'panel',
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    html : 'Hello!',
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()
};
```

Why renderTo don't work in xtype ? 
But this code worked :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.CustomClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myCustomComponent'
});

new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    items : [{
        xtype : 'myCustomComponent',
        html:'World'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below you are not initializing the panel, you need to call it / Pass it to ExtJs to parse and initialize the class. This part of the code is just a Javascript object, ExtJs has no knowledge of it.

```
var myPanel = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    html: 'Hello!',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
};
```

So to initialize this with ExtJs you need to use the Ext.create call as below.

```
var myPanel = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    html: 'Hello!',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
};

Ext.create(myPanel);
```

Also here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gfm) demo

Comment: I have updated my answer, in the top block your using standard JS, ExtJs has no knowledge of it at all. You can mix pure JS with ExtJs to an extent, So for ExtJs to work with this object and intialize the component it needs the call to Ext.create to load the classes and parse the config